# Wordpress responsive horizontal menu with more link

Tags: wordpress

How to convert this awesome menu to wordpress.

Menu demo [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Horizontal-Nav-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS/).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has its own default feature to display a menu with using `wp_nav_menu` function.

You can create a menu from WordPress backend and call it using this function so your menu will be dynamically and you can set the last menu with label `...` and select as a custom link with `#` then you can add another sub child under this menu as well.

You can apply same `CSS` to this menu also to look same as you want.

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: i have already done this. but jquery is not working for this menu . can you make this for me?